# How to Remove all hash character of all values of an array with one line

Tags: php, arrays, hash

I have this array and want to remove all # char from first of all values of it:

```
$array = ('#test' , '#test1' , '#test2' ... etc);
```

I know How I can to remove all special chars with "Foreach" or "for" or any function
But I need to find out is there any way to remove a special character from all values of an array with one or maximum two line in PHP

Kind Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple do an [`array_walk`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php)

```
<?php
$array = ['#test' , '#test1' , '#test2','nohash','#test4'];
array_walk($array,function (&$v){ if(strpos($v,'#')!==false){ $v = str_replace('#','',$v);}},$array);
print_r($array);
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
Array
(
    [0] => test
    [1] => test1
    [2] => test2
    [3] => nohash
    [4] => test4
)
```

Comment: @Mohamm6d, You can use `array_walk` as shown too :).

Comment: Dear @Shankar Damodaran , yes both of them are worked , ill use them

Answer (score 1):

Much simpler if you don't need to test for the first character:

```
$array = str_replace('#', '', $array);
```